# Why is the clause "They filled me in on all the latest news from Cambridge" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, british-english, clauses, logic

Why is it not like the following:

They filled the latest news from Cambridge in me.

Comment: You mean 'Why is it correct?', not 'Why is it true?' _Fill me in_ is a set phrase.

Comment: to fill someone in about something has zero to do with filling some with something. to fill in=a phrasal verb= to provide information about

Answer (score 1):

**To fill in** is very similar to “to fill” – the “in” is an adverb that gives the nuance of putting something *into an empty space that should not be there* so that there is no longer a blank or a hole or an empty space.

For example, you can *fill in* a hole in the road by putting stones into it; you can *fill in* an official form or a question sheet by putting writing into the empty answer boxes.

**”To fill in”**, in the sense you ask about, is an extension of this idea. They put in (= add/insert) news about Cambridge that you lacked and so the fill in the missing part of your knowledge:

“They filled me in on all the latest news from Cambridge” – They added news so as to fill in the news that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *fill* when used in the sense *inform* has a specific complementation pattern:

> *fill* + object + *in* + (prepositional phrase headed by *on*)

The object is the entity being informed and the noun phrase contained in the prepositional phrase headed by *on* is the content of what that entity is being informed of. The prepositional phrase headed by *on* is optional.

The complementation pattern you suggest wouldn't work even with the common definition of *fill*:

> *They filled water in the bottle.

Prepositional verbs often have different complementation patterns than the verbs they are "based" on and the order of elements is fairly rigid.

Comment: I get it....but could we not use: They filled me in with the latest news from Cambridge?

Comment: Why 'on'?....and why filled in, could be filled me with. Why are we using 'in'?

Comment: There is no clear reasoning behind this. A preposition was picked when the use was first popularized and to use anything different would seem out of place. _fill me **with**_ is the standard complementation pattern as in _filled the balloon **with** air_, it's not standard for the construction where _fill_ means _inform_, compare: _We filled the hole in with cement_

Comment: @user385019 It is the same "on" as in "We are having an exam **on** the works of Shakespeare." or "He gave a talk on the life of bees." = *about; concerning; on the subject of*